# How do I make this design database agnostic?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb

I have the following Node.js snippet that uses Mongoose and MongoDB.
How do I make the `UserService` database agnostic so I can swap MongoDB for MySQL?

**app.js**

```
app.get("/users", async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const users = await UserService.listUsers();
        res.json(users);

    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
});
```

**index.js**

```
const User = require("./user_model");
const UserService = require("./user_service");

module.exports = UserService(User);
```

**user_service.js**

```
const listUsers = User => () => {
    return User.find({});
};

module.exports = User => {
    return {
        listUsers: listUsers(User)
    };
};
```

**user_model.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    birthday: String,
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

credit: https://youtu.be/ACzMbQEq_tw

Comment: The usual way - pick (or more likely write your own) ORM that has drivers to use MongoDB and MySQL storages instead of mongoose.

Comment: You are already using mongoose, which sort of locks you into mongodb. So, you probably won't be able to do it without also changing the _user_model_.

As a side note, MySQL now also supports a document-store model similar to MongoDB, maybe that might help.